# Can't login to my Raspberry Pi anymore

Tags: php, linux

I installed this package on my Raspberry Pi:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php
```

And when I rebooted and was going to login with Winscp I got the error message:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods avaible (server sent: publickey)

I'm afraid that I just broke my Pi or something. I don't want to lose my database and all that. What should I do?
I have tried to uninstall it and rebooting but the same message keeps coming up.

Answer (score 1):

in your sshd config file allow password login. and restart ssh. 
First your raspberry pi connect with a screen and then login and make changes to sshd config file as allow password on. Then restart ssh service. and connect with putty or any other client.

Use a Match block at the end of /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Then restart sshd service:

```
service ssh restart
```

Comment: @JoelFransson okay so mark this answer as correct so that other can get benefit of it. if you like